# Custom key mappings visible in dconf don't work

Tags: command-line, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gsettings

I have succeeded in setting custom key commands in the dconf database; the results are visible in *dconf editor* and using *gsettings* (see below).
However, the entered key mappings don't work.

Any ideas why this might be, specific to the dconf database?

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name
'shcut'

$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command
'whiptail --msgbox hello 30 30'

$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding
'<Alt>p'
```

---

EDIT:  Thanks to @Jacob Vlijm 's helpful suggestion:

> gnome-terminal -e "whiptail --msgbox hello 10 10"

the message box appeared.

To send a value to the clipboard from an invoked program, the following will work. Set the shortcut to :

> /bin/bash -e "/home/craig/bin/shcut"

The content of the invoked file is:

> echo "testtext" | xclip -selection clipboard

After that "xclip -selection clipboard" will remain visible as a listed process

```
$ ps -aux | grep xclip
craig     1248  0.0  0.0  29112   308 ?        S    21:20   0:00 xclip -selection clipboard
```

until such time as something else is pasted **into** the clipboard, at which point the process will terminate.

Comment: Seems a command that should run in terminal.  How do you expect the terminal to appear?

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Thanks for your comment.  whiplash (/bin/whiplash) is a standard program on ubuntu which pops up a message box.  It is not a program which outputs to standard out.  Does that make a difference to your comment, or are you saying some programs require explicitly invoking a shell to invoke the desired program?

Comment: Never worked with it, but running the command you mention without a terminal window to run from does nothing. however the command `tilix -e "whiptail --msgbox hello 30 30"`, or in your case probably `gnome-terminal -e "whiptail --msgbox hello 30 30"` does open a terminal and shows something.

Comment: Thanks - the "gnome terminal ..." did the trick of popping up a window.  )To get the text and OK button to appear the size had to be changed to 10 10).  Actually my end goal was to evoke a program which calculated a value and placed it in the clipboard.  I have modified my original question to show this.